# Perl get all command line arguments

Tags: perl, arguments, quotes

I would like to make a small script that color the output in green. I wrote this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use Term::ANSIColor;
my $prg = join(" ",@ARGV);
print(color('green'). `$prg` . color('reset'));
```

Unfortunateyl it is not working because `join('',@argv);` doesn't act as expected. For instance if I pass the arguments : `"foo" "bar"`, I will get `foo bar` without quotes.

How to just get all the command line arguments without removing escape quotes ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're fighting with shell, not perl; try

```
perl script.pl '"foo"' '"bar"'
```

Comment: Is there any POSIX description of how the shell manage the options ? I guess even in C I can only get arguments through (argc argv) not like in windows with the %0 variable... sad